# showing numeric values nicely

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object MyObject that contains a property MyProp that is sometimes numeric. At the moment, I'm showing the number as text like this:

```
$('#MyDiv').text(MyObject.MyProp);
```

I want to add formatting to this number. I can check it's numeric but I'm wondering how to do the number formatting.

```
if ($.isNumeric(MyObject.MyProp) === false) {

   $('#MyDiv').text(MyObject.MyProp);

} else {

   var PrettyNumber = MakePrettyNumber(MyObject.MyProp);
   $('#MyDiv').text(PrettyNumber);
}
```

I'm thinking about looping through the length of the number string and adding commas to separate thousands and add a dot for decimal. Is there a better way? One that doesn't require a plug-in?

Thanks.

Comment: There are no native facilities in any standard JavaScript runtime for doing what you're describing. You'll have to write your own code or use some other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function MakePrettyNumber(x) {
  var res = x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  res = res.replace(/^([^\.]*)$/g, "$1.000");
  return res;
}
```

See here for details: [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: ah ok, regular expressions! Is there a way to also add the decimal dot?

Comment: MakePrettyNumber(12345.6789) result is not pretty

Comment: @frechie do you want to add a decimal point at the end of the number if it doesnt already have one? So, if the input is 123456, then the output should be 123,456.00?

Comment: @frenchie added decimal and 3 zeroes.

Comment: Is there a way to combine this into one regex?